# C++ Unresolved external function IBM Websphere MQ

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008, ibm-mq

I am using IBM Websphere MQ libraries imqb23vn.Lib and imqs23vn.Lib to build a 64-bit C++ application in Visual Studio 2010.

I have downloaded 64-bit versions of the libraries from IBM and put them into the lib directory.

I referenced the directory in the Linker properties under Additional Library Directories. 
Under Linker->Input I included the two libraries under Additional Dependencies.

When I compile the application, I get a bunch of linking errors **LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static inc __cdecl ImqMgr::behavior(void)**.

I am setting this up on a new Windows 2008 64-bit server. The application compiled and worked fine for 9 years in current 32-bit Windows 2003 server environment.

Comment: What version of MQ are you using?

Comment: I am using version 7.5.

Comment: I am able to compile successfully imqsget.cpp with VS2010 SP1 on Windows 2008 R2 Server. Application is also 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

that is the truth. Your linker doesnt find the libs. Check that you use the 64 bit libs and its path and NOT the 32-bit editions.

Comment: I double-checked the version of the files and the path in the project.

Answer (score 0):

First you say:

> I am using IBM Websphere MQ libraries imqb23vn.Lib and imqs23vn.Lib to
>   build a 64-bit C++ application in Visual Studio 2010.

then you say:

> I am setting this up on a new Windows 2008 64-bit server. The
>   application compiled and worked fine for 9 years in current 32-bit
>   Windows 2003 server environment.

Are you building a 32-bit or 64-bit application?  Also, IBM has made changes to the interfaces in the 9 years - sounds like you were using MQ v5.3.

I'm using MS VS 2010 without any issue building both 32-bit and 64-bit applications.  Did you set in your project where to find the MQ libraries?

i.e. For WMQ v7.5 with a default install:

32-bit MQ libraries are at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\Lib\

64-bit MQ libraries are at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\Lib64\

Comment: Roger, thanks for your comment. Yes, I am building a 64 bit version of the application. From everything I found, the libraries are still the same: imqb23vn.Lib, imqc23vn.Lib and imqs23vn.Lib. They were in WMQ v7.5. I got the ones in Lib64 directory you referenced above. I have the libraries in my Lib directory for my project and it is referenced in project properties.